# getting error : Cannot start service db: error while creating mount source path '/var/www/trialriskincident-backend/db-init':

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

i am new here in `docker` my project is in `django` `python`, When i run `sudo docker-compose up` command, i am getting below error in terminal,   can anyone please help me to resolve this issue ?

```
Starting trialriskincident-backend_db_1 ... 
Starting trialriskincident-backend_app_1 ... error

Starting trialriskincident-backend_db_1  ... error
ir /var/www: read-only file system

ERROR: for trialriskincident-backend_db_1  Cannot start service db: error while creating mount source path '/var/www/trialriskincident-backend/db-init': mkdir /var/www: read-only file system

ERROR: for app  Cannot start service app: error while creating mount source path '/var/www/trialriskincident-backend': mkdir /var/www: read-only file system

ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: error while creating mount source path '/var/www/trialriskincident-backend/db-init': mkdir /var/www: read-only file system
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        python-dev \
        default-libmysqlclient-dev \
        && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app
COPY ./ /app
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:

  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"

# Services
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    #restart: no
    environment:
      # Password for root access
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '12345678'
       MYSQL_DATABASE: 'trail_risk_inc_backend'
    ports:
      # <Port exposed> : < MySQL Port running inside container>
      - '3306'
    expose:
      # Opens port 3306 on the container
      - '3306'
      # Where our data will be persisted
    volumes:
      - ./db-init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Answer (score 1):

you are mounting a volume in which you don't have write access **with the container's user**.

Notice that your `sudo` applies to the docker-compose command, but not to the content of the container.

This is a wild guess, but probably you are mounting `/var/www` as a volume to the container, and the container is not run as `root` but as another user, and therefore, that user doesn't have write access to `/var/www`.